# PGN viewer is far too wide when displayed from review

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

Screenshot:

[image: bug]

Think it's pretty obvious what the problem is here. [Here's the suggested edit that the bug appears in](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5858).

Reproduced on both Firefox 38.0 and Chromium 43.0.2357.81 on Ubuntu 14.04.

After a bit of tinkering, the problem appears to be the `width: 900px` CSS on the `table.chess-replayer-board` element. Changing this to `width: 360px` causes the board to display normally.