# Chess viewer does not render properly when viewing edit history

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

[This bug also appears in the review page](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389/10887) and appears to be directly linked. That question was asked over a year ago and still remains.

The PGN viewer has some issues with width in the review edits page, and also in the "view edits" page:

[image: bug]

The amount of distortion varies depending on the question it seems, with no pattern that I can spot. Here, the 8 files of one board seem to be stretched across both boards:

[image: erhm... weird.]